# How to interrupt POST data processing and respond to a client in libmicrohttpd?

Tags: c, http, post

Libmicrohttpd can be used to iteratively process POST data. The problem is that I cannot interrupt POST request and answer to a client until all POST data is recieved. Consider the following code snippet I copied from [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/tutorial.html#largepost_002ec)

```
  {
    struct connection_info_struct *con_info = *con_cls;

    if (0 != *upload_data_size)
    {
      /* Upload not yet done */
      if (0 != con_info->answercode)
      {
        /* we already know the answer, skip rest of upload */
        *upload_data_size = 0;
        return MHD_YES;
      }
      if (MHD_YES !=
          MHD_post_process (con_info->postprocessor,
                            upload_data,
                            *upload_data_size))
      {
        con_info->answerstring = postprocerror;
        con_info->answercode = MHD_HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
      }
      *upload_data_size = 0;

      return MHD_YES;
    }
    /* Upload finished */
    if (NULL != con_info->fp)
    {
      fclose (con_info->fp);
      con_info->fp = NULL;
    }
    if (0 == con_info->answercode)
    {
      /* No errors encountered, declare success */
      con_info->answerstring = completepage;
      con_info->answercode = MHD_HTTP_OK;
    }
    return send_page (connection,
                      con_info->answerstring,
                      con_info->answercode);
  }
```

Here we can see that if any error occurred during post processing then we skip any data that will be send by client and then simply set `upload_data_size` to zero. The problem here, I suppose, is that the data size being sent by client may be exceptionally large. If I try to queue response to a client during post processing (whenever upload_data_size != 0) then MHD_queue_response() returns MHD_NO, which indicates error.
How can I interrupt POST data processing in the middle and respond to a client with an error message without receiving whole data?

Comment: Sending an error won't stop the client which will send all the data then call recv for the response.  If you really want to get out early, break the TCP connection.

Comment: @stark breaking TCP connection is easy -- all I need is to return MHD_NO from handler, but then client wouldn't receive any message, just will get "broken pipe" or something...